# How to install an extension on a private Github using Composer?

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, installation, composer

I'd like to know how to install extensions on my Magento 2.1 using Github / Bitbucket / Gitlab with public and private repositories.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Public Github repository**

Your custom branch name must be prefixed with `"dev-"`.

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/igorw/monolog"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "dev-bugfix"
    }
}
```

**Private Github repository**

Exactly the same solution allows you to work with your private repositories at GitHub and BitBucket:

```
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/my-private-repo": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:vendor/my-private-repo.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

> The only requirement is the installation of SSH keys for a git client.

[Reference here.](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories)

---

**Using the CLI to install**

```
composer config repositories.foo vcs https://github.com/foo/bar
```

After these commands run the command below in the root of your Magento 2 installation.

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento" &&
mage setup:upgrade && 
mage setup:upgrade && mage cache:flush
```