# How can I prepare my Github's extension to install using Composer?

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, composer

Using the question below I've installed extensions hosted on private and public repositories using composer, but I need to create my custom extension now.

[How to install an extension on a private Github using Composer?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175604/how-to-install-an-extension-on-a-private-github-using-composer/175605#175605)

What are the requirements to prepare my extensions on Github to be installed using the composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Key points:**

- Minimum required elements:

  - [Declare component dependencies](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/composer-integration.html) in `composer.json`.
  - [Register](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/component-registration.html) the component using `registration.php`.
  - Component-specific XML definition files:

    - Modules: [module.xml](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/create_component.html)
    - Themes: [theme.xml](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html#fedg_create_theme_how-to_declare)
    - Language packages: [language.xml](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-pack-meta-xml)
- Distribute your component:

  - [Package your component](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/package/package_module.html) in `.zip` format.
  - Use our [validation tool](https://github.com/magento/marketplace-tools) to check your package before you distribute it.
  - If you upload the component to Magento Marketplace, it should be less than 30MB in size.

**Related topics**

- [Introduction to Composer](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/intro/intro-composer.html)
- [Glossary of common terms](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/intro/intro-composer-gloss.html)
- [Sample extensions](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples) created by the Magento 2 Core team
- [Magento 2 Developers Hub](http://magento.com/developers/magento2)