# Magento 2 : how to install magento 2 Extesion using composer from github private repository?

Tags: magento2, composer, github

I have developed one extension and I have uploaded that in my GitHub **private repository**

> https://github.com/bhaveshpp/Percentoffsale

now I have tried to install it using

> composer require --dev bhaveshpp/Percentoffsale

but I got error

> In InitCommand.php line 727:
>                                                                                                                                                                                       Could not find a matching version of package bhaveshpp/Percentoffsale.
>   Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the
>   package is available in a stability w     hich matches your
>   minimum-stability (stable).
>
> require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress]
>   [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev]
>   [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-de pendencies]
>   [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest]
>   [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
>   [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] []...

this is my composer.json file code

```
{
    "name": "bhaveshpp/Percentoffsale",
    "description": "A Magento 2 module that creates discount",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "license": [
      "OSL-3.0",
      "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
      "php": ">=7.0.0",
      "magento/framework": "~100.0.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
      "files": [ "registration.php" ],
      "psr-4": {
        "Zarathemes\\Percentoffsale\\": ""
      }
    }
  }
```

I have also try this solution

> [How to install an extension on a private Github using Composer?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175604/how-to-install-an-extension-on-a-private-github-using-composer)

```
{
    "name": "bhaveshpp/Percentoffsale",
    "description": "A Magento 2 module that creates discount",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "license": [
      "OSL-3.0",
      "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
      "php": ">=7.0.0",
      "magento/framework": "~100.0.4",
      "bhaveshpp/Percentoffsale": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
      "files": [ "registration.php" ],
      "psr-4": {
        "Zarathemes\\Percentoffsale\\": ""
      }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@github.com:bhaveshpp/Percentoffsale.git"
        }
    ]
  }
```

But i have got the same error.

If any one have a solution then provide

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set your repository **Private** to **Public** because the Private repository is not working for this operation.

> Please set your package name in a lower case
>   **"bhaveshpp/Percentoffsale"** to **"bhaveshpp/percentoffsale"**.

Also, Check your GitHub repository into the **"https://packagist.org/"**

This solution will solve your issues.

Try with following **composer.json** file

```
{
    "name": "bhaveshpp/percentoffsale",
    "description": "A Magento 2 module that creates discount",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": "true",
    "license": "OSL-3.0",  
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "bhaveshpp/percentoffsale":"dev-master@dev"
    },
    "autoload": {
      "files": 
        [ 
            "registration.php" 
        ],
      "psr-4": {
            "Zarathemes\\Percentoffsale\\": ""
        }
    }
  }
```

In Github Repository, Release and Add a Tag.

Comment: it is usefull but my repository is private so it is not work for me thank you

Comment: First I have approved this extension by setting public repository and then it will install

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
"repositories": {
    "bhaveshpp-percentoffsale": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "your_ssh_path_to_repo"
    }
}
```

Then execute "composer require bhaveshpp/percentoffsale"

Comment: thanku but it is not valid json format so it not work

Comment: updated my comment, try to convert package name to lower case and use only figure brackets